# UserControl is not displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

EDIT: It seems like that I needed to change the height of RowDefinition. Thanks goes to Alvaro. However:
how do I reference different elements inside my usercontrol (change their properties), when I want to change them in MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs?

I have two XAML files in the same namespace.

MainWindow.xaml

List.xaml

When I try to add List.xaml usercontrol to my mainwindow xaml (that is insert xaml from another file), it does not show up.

I insert usercontrol that exists in Lemosystem namespace and inside View folder.

```
xmlns:lemoview="clr-namespace:Lemosystem.View"
```

I add usercontrol to my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<lemoview:List/>
```

Nothing shows up. Here is my List XAML (code is the default):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Lemosystem.View.List"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="What do you want to do today?" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,96,-83,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="44" Width="373" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I expect the label from my usercontrol to show up in MainWindow.xaml GUI, but it doesn't.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Lemosystem.View.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:lemocontroller="clr-namespace:Lemosystem.Controller"
        xmlns:lemoview="clr-namespace:Lemosystem.View"
        Title="{Binding Path=SystemName}" Height="603" Width="827"
        ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        >
    <Grid Name="Window" Margin="0,0,2,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

...

<lemoview:List/>

...

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And how do I reference different elements inside my usercontrol (change their properties), when I want to change them in MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.xaml.cs?

Comment: Please add the content of MainWindow.xaml

Comment: remove your height ="0*" !!! make it "Auto"

Comment: I added a part of it, because its quite big and what I omitted are just some grids, which should not be over my label (I move the label down the code).

Comment: Thanks, Alvaro. Now I can actually see the label. However, how do I reference elements inside List.xaml (like text boxes and so on) in both MainWindow.xaml and its code?

Comment: why do you need it in mainwindow.xaml ?

Comment: Because I reuse List.xaml in several pages in my GUI simply by changing label text and a few other elements to avoid boiler plate code.

Comment: Create a ViewModel for your list.xaml, bind all the components that are supposed to be change thier values to properties in your viewModel. and then, for each List.Xaml (control) in your mainWindow, you will have a viewModel binded to it, and by changing the values of these viewModels, the components will display the new values.

Comment: When you say ViewModel of List.xaml, you mean List.xaml.cs? And then just make some attributes, which are data bound to elements in GUI? How do I reference those attributes from MainWindow.xaml then (because I need to open List.xaml, when user presses on a button in MainWindow.xaml)?

Comment: I will post for you an answer in 10 minutes !

Comment: Very nice! I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you tell me, where do you enter the information to show in your list control, when clicking on the button ?

Comment: Information is supposed to be changed by the button's method, which was pressed (MainWindow ViewModel). I have many buttons and each of them has to open List.xaml, but with different content of some labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I created a project with :

List.Xaml

```
  <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.List"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding TextToDisplay}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="10,96,-83,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Height="44"
           Width="373"
           FontSize="24"
           FontWeight="Bold" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ListViewModel.cs:

```
    public class ListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }


    private string textToDisplay;
    public string TextToDisplay
    {
        get { return textToDisplay; }
        set { textToDisplay = value; OnPropertyChanged("TextToDisplay"); }
    }

    public ListViewModel(string value)
    {
        TextToDisplay = value;
    }
}
}
```

MainWindow.Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:lemoview="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Click Me" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_OnClick"></Button>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"></ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
      public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        MyList=new ObservableCollection<ListViewModel>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ListViewModel> myList;
    public ObservableCollection<ListViewModel> MyList
    {
        get { return myList; }
        set { myList = value; }
    }

    private void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyList.Add(new ListViewModel("MyValue"));
    }
}
```

App.xaml:

```
    <Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type wpfApplication1:ListViewModel}">
        <wpfApplication1:List />
    </DataTemplate>

</Application.Resources>
```

in App.xaml, I just defined the binding between List.xaml and ListViewModel.cs

the viewModel of MainWindow is itself.

after every Click on the button, a new ViewModel is created, added to the list with a defined value (you will need to modify this part, to set the value you want).

I hope it will help you ! it works for me.

Comment: thank you very much! I'll try it out and write you later if I experience any problems :)

Answer (score 1):

How do you like to show something, if you put it il a row that has height ="0" ?

change it to :

```
<Window x:Class="Lemosystem.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:lemocontroller="clr-namespace:Lemosystem.Controller"
    xmlns:lemoview="clr-namespace:Lemosystem.View"
    Title="{Binding Path=SystemName}" Height="603" Width="827"
    ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
    >
<Grid Name="Window" Margin="0,0,2,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <lemoview:List/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, Alvaro. Now I can actually see the label. However, how do I reference elements inside List.xaml (like text boxes and so on) in both MainWindow.xaml and its code?

Comment: Create a ViewModel for your list.xaml, bind all the components that are supposed to be change thier values to properties in your viewModel. and then, for each List (control) in your mainWindow, you will have a viewModel binded to it, and by changing the values of these viewModels, the components will display the new values.

Comment: @decas xaml doesn't work that way, when you have a usercontrol inside a view it's not a xaml dumped into another xaml, the usercontrol is an entity of itself and the view containing it only has access to it's exposed properties.

Comment: no one said that it's a dumped xaml ! it's a control used in a window ! and if it's used many times with different values, better to make it dynamic by creating a viewModel and then changing values of it's properties !

Comment: @mot, then I'll need to rethink my design, because I enable/disable different grids when navigating in GUI window.

Comment: @Alvaro, how do I change those values, when a user clicks a button in MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: @decas You can add a dependency property to your user control to control these visibillities

Comment: @mot, If you mean to turn off the whole UserControl, then the same can be done just by encapsulating it with for example Grid and by disabling the grid. However, the question is how to control List from outside, so that it produce elements with different values?

Comment: @mot, List.xaml is a UserControl, which has lets say labels. When a user clicks a button in MainWindow.xaml, a new page should open (that is List.xaml), but the content of labels is changed accordingly to which button was pressed. I have to have some control over List.xaml, so that I could change the content of labels.

Comment: @decas I see. I think your concept of what is a user control in wpf is a wrong, and it's a bit too much to explain in a comment. I suggest you read an article about the subject and things should be easier for you from there.